# Are hall effect sensors ratiometric?

Tags: sensor, hall-effect

I am working on the Arduino magnetic levitation project and it requires "ratiometric" hall effect sensors. On amazon and adafruit there are no hall effect sensors that are explicitly "ratiometric". Based on a quick google search I know that being ratiometric means its output changes based on a change input or supply voltage, but this makes it seem like all Hall Effect Sensors are ratiometric. Can I buy whatever is on amazon or do I need to go elsewhere and buy a *ratiometric* hall effect sensor?

Thank you, the help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Most are ratiometric .So under normal applications you want to keep the supply volts constant .Example if 400 amps means 1.5 volts output with a supply volts of 5VDC .If you keep 400 Amps but move the 5VDC to say 5.5VDC your expected output will be 1.65VDC and if you reduced the supply to 4.5VDC then expect a 1.35VDC output .I have discussed small supply volts variations .Large variations are limited by max ratings and the min volts for the internal opamp to work .

Comment: Thank you, I read a bit more about it as well and it seem that I will just buy a linear hall effect sensor. Thank you for the examples they helped me understand what the sensor is doing a bit better. :)